# Scss mixin ignoring @if statement

Tags: html, sass, scss-mixins

I am doing an assessment where I'm asked to render content to an html file with blank tags using only css.  I created a mixin that uses the counter-increment property to number all li elements in the document.  I am trying to replace every 3rd li with 'fizz' but I can't seem to create an if statement that works.  Here's what I have:

Html

```
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>FizzBuzz</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css" />
</head>

<body>
  <ul>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
  </ul>
</body>

</html>
```

SCSS

```
@mixin render {
  @for $i from 1 through 16 {
    ul:nth-child(#{$i}) {
      :before {
        @if $i % 3 == 0 {
          content: 'fizz';
          counter-increment: number-counter;
        } @else {
          content: counter(number-counter);
          counter-increment: number-counter;
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

body {
  counter-reset: number-counter 0;
  @include render();
}

li {
  list-style-type: none;
}
```

Comment: other issue : I assume you're targeting the nth `li`, child of `ul`. `ul:nth-child` means "the last `ul` **in its parent**. So `li:nth-child` should work better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you're targeting `ul:nth-child` instead of `ul li:nth-child`. Also should be using `&:before` instead of just `:before`.

```css
@mixin render {
  @for $i from 1 through 16 {
    ul li:nth-child(#{$i}) {
      order: #{$i};
      
      &:before {
        @if $i % 3 == 0 {
          content: 'fizz';
          counter-increment: number-counter;
        } @else {
          content: counter(number-counter);
          counter-increment: number-counter;
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi ! Seeking the posts, I love learning new things :) But as is, your snippet does not show anything. Would you integrate the html part to it please, to let us see and applause ? :)

Comment: @Philippe Stack Overflow editor doesn't support SCSS/SASS rendering I believe, so setting this up in Codepen, you would be able to see the result

Comment: Works fine with Codepen. Congrats !